Is there any way we can get the time taken to generate response in azure chat playground?
I am trying few prompts in azure AI chat playground using gpt-4o. I am putting a prompt, context and query the required fields and generating the response. Please refer below image for the playground.
I want to check how much time it is taking to hit one query and generate response. Is there any way we can check this?  I am not able to find any analytics feature in playground.


Not as far as I know of. Typically the playground isn't meant for that kind of measurements. Even if it supported it it might not reflect real world results.

check in resource monitor.

Check the below solution @noobmaster

You check this in the azure OpenAI resource monitor tab.
Go to Metrics tab in your OpenAI resource.

Select  Azure OpenAI Requests metric

Next, click on Add metric and select Time to Last byte metric or Time to Response

Both of this will tell you the response time.
But Time to Response applies to PTU and PTU-managed deployments.
But to view more metrics correctly, you need to enable
Diagnostic settings

Next, select the metrics and Log Analytics workspace.

After enabling go to the selected Log Analytics workspace and query the AzureMetrics table under Cognitive Services

You will get the detailed logs.
In Latency metric name you will find the time.

Check this documentation for monitoring metric in Azure OpenAI
